# Change comboBox options depending on the selected item of a previous comboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

How to change `comboBox` options depending on the selected item of a previous `comboBox`? I tried like this but seems like I'm doing something wrong!

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Virsraksts formai
    this.Text = "Atpūtas vietas meklēšana";

    // Izvelieties valodu
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Latviešu");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Krievu");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Angļu");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Vācu");

    // Izveleties novadu
    comboBox2.Items.Add("Zemgale");
    comboBox2.Items.Add("Latgale");
    comboBox2.Items.Add("Kurzeme");
    comboBox2.Items.Add("Vidzeme");

    // Izveleties atputas veidu
    comboBox3.Items.Add("Slēpošana");
    comboBox3.Items.Add("Kalnā kāpšana");
    comboBox3.Items.Add("Sporta aktivitātes");
    comboBox3.Items.Add("Latvijas apskates objekti");

    // Izveleties atputas vietu
    if(comboBox2.Text == "Zemgale")
    {
        comboBox4.Items.Clear();
        comboBox4.Items.Add("Jelgava");
    }
    // Izveleties atputas vietu
    if (comboBox2.Text == "Latgale")
    {
        comboBox4.Items.Clear();
        comboBox4.Items.Add("Daugavpils");
    }

}
```

So basically after selecting `comboBox2` items, it doesn't show anything in `comboBox4`.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? What does and doesn't happen when you execute?

Comment: No errors, but it doesn't show the comboBox4 items.

Comment: I think the problem is with your if statement, you should check selected item, not text

Comment: Please explain what is happening.
The if-statements, where in your code are they placed? In an event handler for Combobox2 (SelectedIndexChanged)?

Comment: edited the post with a full code at the moment.

Comment: Put your `If` codeblock in the evnethandler of `comboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged`. `Form_Load` event raised only once

Comment: Why you need `combobox4`? From your code `combobox4` will have always only one or no values. - Use checkbox maybe in that case

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Izveleties atputas vietu
        if(comboBox2.SelectedText == "Zemgale")
        {
            comboBox4.Items.Clear();
            comboBox4.Items.Add("Jelgava");
        }
        // Izveleties atputas vietu
        if (comboBox2.SelectedText == "Latgale")
        {
            comboBox4.Items.Clear();
            comboBox4.Items.Add("Daugavpils");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Had to write the if statements into (comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged) and not in the Form_Load.

Comment: Thats the answer @Darshan Patel gave you.

Comment: Check my answer for a nicer way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    comboBox2.Items.Add("Zemgale");
    comboBox2.Items.Add("Latgale");
    comboBox2.Items.Add("Kurzeme");
    comboBox2.Items.Add("Vidzeme");

    comboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged;
}

void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox2.Text == "Zemgale")
    {
        comboBox4.Items.Clear();
        comboBox4.Items.Add("Jelgava");
    }

    if (comboBox2.Text == "Latgale")
    {
        comboBox4.Items.Clear();
        comboBox4.Items.Add("Daugavpils");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of code review.

This code is easier to read and is more maintanable than the multiple if statements. Also, don't repeat clearing the combobox4, just clear it every time the selected index changed on combobox2?

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox4.Items.Clear();

    switch(comboBox2.SelectedText)
    {
        case "Zemgale":
            comboBox4.Items.Add("Jelgava");
            break;
        case "Latgale":
            comboBox4.Items.Add("Daugavpils");
            break;
    }
}
```